# Flutter how to rebuild widget

Tags: flutter, widget, rebuild

My question might sound weird but is there a way to rebuild a widget without using setState or any button click ?

Edit: I have a listview.builder i need it rebuild itself every time any modification happend to the list

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its a statefull widget then `setState() {}` is enough to make it rebuild, otherwise it depends what state management you are using, if provider, it would be notifyListeners() for example

Comment: where exactly to use setState () {} ? i don't want to click on anything to reload the page

Comment: Where do you update the list?

Comment: on setState on class Named Prochaines() not where the the list is declared, someone adviced me to create method to update the list and call it on callback, i didn't really understant what he was talking about .....

Comment: If you have multiple classes using same list i would look into state management options, this is what it is for

Comment: Is it easier if i had the data on database ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a widget or variable used in a widget and that changes, you can use **Obx**

Obx in Get X is a way for this solution.

see this link: https://morioh.com/p/6a81be41aa4b